# Decapitalize MenuItem text in APIs lower 23

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-view, android-toolbar, menuitem

I want to decapitalize the menu item text in kitkat and lollipop devices but fortunately its working on marshmallow and nougat. I found many solution regarding this problem but everything works in nougat and marshmallow but not in lollipop and below devices here is my code

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/MyMenuTextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="MyMenuTextAppearance" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

Same Code in marshmallow looks like this:
    [image: Marshmallow menuitem]

But in lollipop and kitkat it looks this:
    [image: Lollipop menuitem]

Please help me to get a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/MyMenuTextAppearance</item>
```

Do:

```
<item name="actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/MyMenuTextAppearance</item>
```

**Update**

For pre-lollipop devices add this to your `dimens.xml`:

```
<bool name="abc_config_actionMenuItemAllCaps" tools:override="true">false</bool>
```

Comment: thanks dude but it just changes the style of text not able to make it to lowercase

Comment: I tested this code [on API 22 emulator](http://i.imgur.com/BouLeGr.png).

Comment: Sorry azizbekian you are right its working on lollipop thanks , i was not getting it right because i was on kitkat device so please can you tell me the solution for kitkat device too

Comment: @Sudhansu, I see. Let me investigate that.

Comment: thank you so much azizbekian please update me when you get any solution :)